# NiFi PutHiveStreaming all or nothing

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

Is there a proper way to configure or use the `PutHiveStreaming` processor in Apache NiFi to stream avro files into a Hive database using some sort of all or nothing method. I don't want to use the Rollback on Failure option, because this would lead to a full queue if more data would stream into the processor and block them.

I wasn't able to find a proper instruction for the **Records per Transaction**, but I think this should be the way to go. Isn't it? It allows ExpressionLanguage and I was thinking about using the exact amount of records as configuration to ensure that either the whole data from the FlowFile is insert or nothing. See above my current configuration from the processor. It works fine but I wan't to be sure not to create duplicates within the Hive table in case of a down time of my nodes and unfinished tasks. The pipeline would then reload the latest unfinished data.

[image]

Comment: Yes if you can set Records Per Transaction to the exact number of records you'll be good, then you can set Transactions Per Batch to 1

Comment: Hi @mattyb thanks for your answer. Sadly it's not allowed to set the Transactions per Batch to 1

Comment: Then 2 should be fine, can't remember why you can't set it to 1...